# Comparing WebSocket and Traditional TCP Chat: Similarities and Differences

Tags: spring-boot, sockets, websocket, tcp, protocols

I'd like to ask a question: What are the differences between WebSocket and the traditional TCP chat code based on traditional NIO? I feel like they have a similar approach, both using a HashMap to store client-server connections, and the sender requests the server, which then queries the receiving user's socket/session to complete the message sending. Are they the same? If not, what are the differences?
WebSocket:

```
public class Server {

...

public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Server> WEBSOCKET_MAP = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
public Session session;
public String userId;
...
public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam("id") String id){
...
//give session to Server and rigister to  WEBSOCKET_MAP
}
public void onMessage(String tmp) {
    System.out.println(tmp);
    Message cur = JSON.parseObject(tmp, Message.class);
    Integer fromUserId = cur.getFromId();
    Integer toUserId = cur.getToId();
    //them find receiver session through ConcurrentHashMap WEBSOCKET_MAP and do a sending by API session.getAsyncRemote().sendText(JSON.toJSONString(message));
    ...
}
...}
```

Traditional TCP:

```
public class ChatServer {
private ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel;
private Selector selector;
private Map<SocketChannel, String> clientMap;

public void start(int port) throws IOException {
serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
serverSocketChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
selector = Selector.open();
serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
clientMap = new HashMap<>();
System.out.println("Chat Server started on port " + port);
while (true) {
    selector.select();
    Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
    Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = selectedKeys.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();

        if (key.isAcceptable()) {
            handleAccept(key);
        } else if (key.isReadable()) {
            handleRead(key);
        }
    }
}...
private void sendPrivateMessage(String sender, String recipient, String message) throws 
IOException {
    for (Map.Entry<SocketChannel, String> entry : clientMap.entrySet()) {
        SocketChannel clientChannel = entry.getKey();
        String clientId = entry.getValue();

    if (clientId.equals(recipient)) {
        String privateMessage = "[Private from " + sender + "]: " + message;
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(privateMessage.getBytes());
        clientChannel.write(buffer);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: As @SteffenUllrich mentioned, pure TCP requires message framing, ie construction of messages from a continuous stream of bytes;this can be a quite tedious work.

Answer (score 1):

WebSocket is a **message oriented** protocol on top of HTTP (or better: preceded by a HTTP request and response). It is **designed to work everywhere where HTTP and HTTPS are working**, i.e. even when there are restrictive firewalls blocking access to ports other than 80/443 or even when firewalls do deep packet inspection to block everything apart from HTTP and HTTPS.

Normal TCP sockets are instead a **stream oriented** protocol. TCP does not have a concept of a message, this needs to be implemented in the application protocol. It is also not uncommon that ports apart from 80/443 or application protocols apart from HTTP/HTTPS are blocked, especially in companies and sometimes also hotels.

Comment: But for a chat function, we only need senderId, receiverId and content, for websocket we need to put it in header or body; for traditional TCP we need to separate it by " " or orther symbol. I think the difficulty of Implementation are almost the same, and I wonder the different of performance such as throughput and response time.

Comment: @YuXing: There is likely no significant difference in performance and complexity of implementation.